# Appengine create a google calendar event (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-calendar-api

I am trying to achieve that a google calendar event is being created for a user that visits a certain page in my appengine application. I assume that the user is always logged into his google account and I played around a little bit as you can see below but I am always receiving this error message:

"NameError: global name 'service' is not defined"

Here is what I tried:

```
import atom
import gdata.apps.service
```

.............

class Test(webapp2.RequestHandler):

```
def get(self):

    event = {
      'summary': 'Appointment',
      'location': 'Somewhere',
      'start': {
        'dateTime': '2011-06-03T10:00:00.000-07:00'
      },
      'end': {
        'dateTime': '2011-06-03T10:25:00.000-07:00'
      },
      'attendees': [
        {
          'email': 'attendeeEmail',
          # Other attendee's data...
        },
        # ...
      ],
    }

    created_event = gdata.apps.service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()


    template_values = {       
    }

    template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('test.html')
    self.response.write(template.render(template_values))
```

Do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: If you import gdata.apps.service than you access it using gdata.apps.service. I think what you want is from gdata.apps import service

Comment: Thank you for your response, you are right and I changed this in the code accordingly. Nevertheless, I am now receiving another error message stating:

"created_event = gdata.apps.service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'events'"

Do you have any ideas why this is happening?